# d3 text all over the place and not in the right places

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a linechart based off of the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955. I'm not using temperatures but rather value levels from 0-1 that I call sentiments.

I'm not using a tsv file either, but rather rendering JSON in real time through an AJAX call where my data object is an array with objects in it:

```
[{date: '20140716', ESPN.com: 0.4, SI.com: 0.5})]
```

There are typically multiple dates in an array and at least 6-7 websites (they're included in every object).

The code looks like this:

```
function renderHistoricalData(array) {


var data = array;

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

  var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .defined(function(d) { return d.y!=0; })
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.sentiment); });

  var svg = d3.select("#historical_chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);

    var sites = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {date: d.date, sentiment: +d[name]};
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(sites, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.sentiment; }); }),
      d3.max(sites, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.sentiment; }); })
      ]);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Sentiment (%)");

    var site = svg.selectAll(".site")
    .data(sites)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "site");

    site.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    site.append("text")
    .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.sentiment) + ")"; })
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
        // .style("text-anchor", "inherit")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
      });
}
```

This results in something that looks like: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgErb.jpg

Any ideas? I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: If I read your code correctly you're appending new axes etc for each site in your data?

Comment: What I was trying to do was append the title of a news source to the end of that line.

Comment: Well you have a `data.forEach()` loop and within that you're creating axes etc. That shouldn't happen in a loop, just once.

Comment: That could be the problem then. In the original example, there was a tsv being loaded (I don't have that option with my app) and a data.forEach() only incorporated the d.date = parseData(d.date).
 
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Move the code to create the axes outside the loop.

Comment: I'm relatively new to d3, do you mean take all the svg.append and site.append stuff out of the loop?

Comment: Where you `.call(xAxis)` and `.call(yAxis)`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! The site names are still being displayed on the y axis instead of at the end of the line. Any ideas?

Comment: Check how you're setting its position and whether all the values you're using there are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Sorry, went away for a few days. It seems this is the line giving me grief: .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.sentiment) + ")"; }) (as part of site.append('text') but no matter what I change, it doesn't look right

Comment: Did you check whether all the values you're using there are what you'd expect?

Comment: Yeah, they're organized in the correct format and the sources are consistent throughout each data object.

Comment: Well it looks like it should work. Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle but it's not rendering http://jsfiddle.net/rL5vR/

Comment: You can also try it yourself. I've loaded the site onto heroku http://news-lean.herokuapp.com. If you search for a topic, I've been using 'Lebron' and 'Sports' as a default, it should return the broken chart when you click the history button.

Comment: I've fixed the errors in the fiddle and a few other things [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rL5vR/4/). It looks like the root cause of your problem was that you're assuming that the data is sorted starting with the earliest date when it wasn't (the opposite actually). Is that what you're looking for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that in the code

```
{name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}
```

you're assuming that `values` are sorted by date, latest date last. In your data, the opposite is the case -- the latest date is first. Therefore, your text appears at the beginning of the x axis. To fix, simply sort your data.

I've fixed this and a few other things [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rL5vR/4/).